# Use getters and setters to create string from 1-7 integers

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to take a 1-7 integer value and print out a day for each value with an enum.

I get an error in the class mapping from firestore, "isn't a field in the enclosing class"

So if 1 is passed in then "Monday" is given
   if 2 is passed in then "Tuesday" is given

```
enum _Days {
  Monday,
  Tuesday,
  Wednesday,
  Thursday,
  Friday,
  Saturday,
  Sunday
}

class HeadingItem implements ListItem {
  String _weekday;
  final int time;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  set day(int weekday) {
    var value = _Days.values[weekday - 1].toString();
    var idx = value.indexOf(".") + 1;
    var result = value.substring(idx, value.length);
    _weekday = result;
  }

  String get day {
    return _weekday;
  }

  HeadingItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['day'] != null),
        assert(map['time'] != null),
        day = map['day'], // 'day' isn't a field in the enclosing class  <--- this is the error that im stuck on...
        time = map['time'];

  HeadingItem.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in your code, `day` is technically a set of *methods* of `this` that allows us to work with `day` *as if* it were a *member* of `this`; `day` is not actually a member.

Thus, in order for your initializer list to work as you intended it to, it would already need to have access to `this` in order to provide the functionality you want (for example, to set the value of the internal member `_weekday`).

However, as mentioned in the [Language Tour of Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#using-class-members) in the section on *Initializer Lists*, the initializer list does not have access to `this`. Rather we should see the initializer list as values to assign to members of `this` during the instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
String get day {
  return _weekday;
}
```

to this

```
String day = _weekday;
```

Comment: I think that the point is to have day consistently return the value of _weekday. In this code there is no guarantee that this would happen.